# Ubuntu 12.04 Freezes

Tags: 12.04

Hello I recently moved from windows to ubuntu 12.04 64Bit

My system freezes up when I open up the file manager or Intellij IDEA, or randomly on all kind of "heavy" operations.

This did not occur on windows so I do not think it's a hardware problem.

I've read that this may be the cause of nvidia drivers, but I tried following several guides on how to update my nvidia drivers but to no avail (I have a nvidia 9600gt)

I have now tty mode while freezing, I saw a lot of Nouveau errors, so I'm pretty sure this is my problem, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: System will freeze and show graphical glitches ever so often.
Reason: My graphic card is not suitable for the open source Nouveau drivers.

Solution:

1. Download the correct driver for your card via Nvidia site (Mine was 340 for 9600GT)
2. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add the line `blacklist nouveau` to the end of the file.
3. Reboot your system.
4. Enter tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
5. Type `sudo service lightdm stop` (this will close your desktop)
6. Give permissions to the nvidia driver like so: `sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.58.run`
7. Run the file like so : `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.58.run` and follow instructions.
8. After all is done and well type `sudo service lightdm start`
9. Go back to desktop (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)